# Where to find the location of hive database when i am giving the location?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I am creating a database and I am giving the location like this:

```
create database talent loaction '/home/hadoop';
```

OR

```
create database talent location '/Input';
```

Input is the folder that I created in HDFS.

but when I check in this location I am not getting this database.

I can see the databases in warehouse that I created without giving the location.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who arrived at this page looking to find the location on HDFS of a database `your_database_name`, you can get that with the following:

```sql
DESCRIBE DATABASE EXTENDED your_database_name
```

For example in PySpark:

```py
sqlContext.sql('DESCRIBE DATABASE EXTENDED your_database_name').toPandas()
```

Answer (score 2):

when you create database without using location like `create database talent` ,it will create in by default location `/user/hive/warehouse` in hdfs. You can see in hdfs by using command

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse
```

if you create database using location then it will create the db in given location.

```
create database talent location '/Input';
```

You can see the db using command

```
hdfs dfs -ls /Input
```

Comment: I checked.. Its not there.. I am able to see database in warehouse.... but not getting those to which I gave any location.... I checked through the browser also.. there is no database in /Input... but when I run show databases;  name is listed dere only